# Check if variable is a number smaller than a given number or equal to the text "QUIT"

Tags: bash

I would to stay in this loop as long as $CHOICE is not "QUIT" or a number smaller than a given integer (variable).

I'm using this : (22 as an example)

```
NUMBER=22
CHOICE=99
while [ "$CHOICE" -gt "$NUMBER" ] && [ "$CHOICE" != "QUIT" ]; do
  read CHOICE < /dev/tty
done
```

But if I put let's say "test", the script crashes because it is expecting an integer in the first test.

What can I do to avoid this crash ?

Comment: What's your shell / version?

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.19

Comment: what do you want to do with inputs that are not numbers and not `QUIT`?

Comment: stay in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will loop while CHOICE is not "QUIT" or an integer less than NUMBER:

```
NUMBER=22
while :; do
    read CHOICE
    case $CHOICE in
        QUIT) break;;
        *[!0-9]*|'') ;;
        *) test "$CHOICE" -lt "$NUMBER" && break;;
    esac
done
```

If you also want the loop to exit when the user enters ^D, you should put the `read` as the loop condition: `while read CHOICE; do case $CHOICE ...`.

Comment: Agreed, I simplified my example too quickly, edited to CHOICE=99, but your code doesn't solve anything : `CHOICE=99; while [ "0${CHOICE%%[!0-9]*}" -gt 10 ]; do read CHOICE < /dev/tty; done` Any letter or word stop the loop.

Comment: This type of loop is indeed much better, I simplified my example with the number 10, but it's actually a variable (integer, can be for example 15, or 10) so I can't use [0-9]

Comment: then please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: edited content and title

Comment: Alright I got it : `while :; do read CHOICE; if [ "$CHOICE" == "QUIT" ] || [[ $CHOICE < 10 ]]; then break; fi; done`

Comment: Ah if not empty too : `while :; do read CHOICE; if [ "$CHOICE" == "QUIT" ] || ( [[ $CHOICE < 10 ]] && [ "$CHOICE" != "" ] ); then break; fi; done`

Comment: @bobdylan, note that `<` is a lexicographic comparison, i.e `[[ 100 < 21 ]]` is true.

Comment: Noted ! I guess add `"") ;;` or something doing the same thing for empty string and it's perfect :) Thanks

Comment: Oh my bad now you have `|''`, it's fine no need to edit

Answer (score 1):

Tweaks of [*mosvy*'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472276/165517):

```
NUMBER=22
while read CHOICE ; do
  case "${CHOICE}" in
        QUIT)   break ;;
    *[!0-9]*)   ;;
          ?*)   [ "${CHOICE}" -lt $NUMBER ] && break ;;
  esac
done
```

- Don't put `read` in the loop.
- No need to initialize `$CHOICE`, and
- changed `*)` to `?*)`, making one less conditional -- *mosvy*'s `|''` can just fall through.

Answer (score 0):

You may need an additional test for alpha characters, like

```
while [ "$CHOICE" != "QUIT" ] && { [ "${CHOICE//[[:alpha:]]}" != "$CHOICE" ] || [ "$CHOICE" -gt 10 ]; }
  do    read CHOICE < /dev/tty
  done
```

Comment: It is working, but with "QUIT" I have `bash: [: QUIT: integer expression expected`

Comment: Rats! You're right; introduced a compound expression with braces; pls try again.

Comment: @ilkkachu: thanks for editing the newly introduced error...